# SOLVED Django historical records not showing up in admin

Tags: django, historical-db

I am setting historical record for some of my models. It works, the table is created and behaves as expected, however, I can not get it to appear in my admin tables.

models.py

```
class Test(models.Model):
    ...
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

In admin.py I have a TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin) such as:

```
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('test', 'id')
    list_filter = ['test']


admin.site.register(Test, TestAdmin) #1
# admin.site.register(Test, SimpleHistoryAdmin) #2
```

When I use the #1 line I have everything working well except that I don't have the historical table. When I use the #2 line I don't get it neither and my format doesn't work anymore. When I set both I get an error `django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model Test is already registered with 'test.TestAdmin'` (that makes sens).

What am I missing to get the historical record table appears in my admin?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why not let it inherit from `SimpleHistoryAdmin`.

Answer (score 2):

You should *subclass* the `SimpleHistoryAdmin` as is specified in the [*Displaying custom columns in the admin history list view* section of the documentation](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.0/admin.html#displaying-custom-columns-in-the-admin-history-list-view):

```
class TestAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin):
    list_display = ('test', 'id')
    history_list_display = ['test']
    list_filter = ['test']

admin.site.register(Test, TestAdmin)
```

Comment: I have already tried that too. Double check now and still no change nowhere. Am I supposed to have a new table appearing in the main admin section? Nothing here neither in the specific table. Thanks for your time Willem Van Onsem.

Comment: @yoarch: ah, but you forgot to specify the `history_list_display`: the columns of history you want to display.

Comment: Did not notice it indeed. No change. Nothing appears. I must be missing something.

Comment: @yoarch: but you did subclass from `SimpleHistoryAdmin`? So `TestAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin)`? (notice the "parent class" is not `ModelAdmin`).

Comment: Yes I do. I set that in the admin.py file. Checking everything, seems to be the same as all the documentations.

Comment: It works. Sorry ! It works from the beginning. To see it we have to go until the instance of the class in the admin UI, click on it and here there is a button HISTORY at the top right. Sorry for that. Should I do something special to clean this post?

Comment: @yoarch, your doubt was absolutely valid. Even I didn't notice it and was searching for this. thank you :)